Finite difference scheme for non-standart PDE (bicylindrical coords)
Mathematical formulation of the problem:
There is the Aifantis equation for the elasticity gradient
$$
\eta =\lambda \left( \operatorname{tr}\ \varepsilon  \right)l+2G\varepsilon -c{{\nabla }^{2}}\left[ \lambda \left( \operatorname{tr}\ \varepsilon  \right)\mathbf{l}+2G\varepsilon  \right]
$$
The values of mechanical stresses $\eta$ are directly specified. Need to find values
$$
\varepsilon =\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{\varepsilon }_{11}} & 0  \\
   0 & {{\varepsilon }_{22}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right).
$$
Let us introduce some replacement $2G\left( {{\varepsilon }_{11}}-{{\varepsilon }_{22}} \right)=\gamma$ for the equation
$$
{{\eta }_{11}}-{{\eta }_{21}}=2G( {{\varepsilon }_{11}}-{{\varepsilon }_{22}} )-c{{\nabla }^{2}} \left( 2G ({{\varepsilon }_{11}}-{{\varepsilon }_{22}}) \right) 
$$
We obtain equation:
$$
{{\nabla }^{2}}\gamma -\frac{\gamma }{c}=\frac{{{\eta }_{11}}-{{\eta }_{21}}}{c}
$$
Replacing the right-hand side in the equation above with
$$
\frac{\eta_{11} - \eta_{21}}{c} = \eta
$$
for $\eta = const$ we obtained the following partial differential equation
$$
\frac{1}{{{}^{2}}}{{\left( ch\tau -\cos \sigma  \right)}^{2}}\left( \frac{{{\partial }^{2}}\gamma }{\partial {{\sigma }^{2}}}+\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}\gamma }{\partial {{\tau }^{2}}} \right)-{{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \right)}^{2}} =\eta 
$$
Using substition $\gamma = c(u - \eta)$, $a^2=c$, and $u=\sqrt{2(\cosh{\tau}-\cos{\sigma})}$ we obtain equation:
$$
{(\cosh{\tau} - \cos{\sigma})}^{2} \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \sigma^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \tau^2} \right) - u = 0 \tag{1}
$$
Here in this case, $\sigma,\tau$ are bicylindrical coordinates,
$$
{\displaystyle \left\{{\begin{matrix}x={\frac {a\,\mathrm {sh} \,\tau }{\mathrm {ch} \,\tau -\cos \sigma }}\\y={\frac {a\sin \sigma }{\mathrm {ch} \,\tau -\cos \sigma }}\end{matrix}}\right.}
$$
where ${\displaystyle 0\leqslant \sigma <\pi }$, ${\displaystyle -\infty <\tau <\infty }$.
I should get numerical solution for $u$ and final find ${\varepsilon }_{11}, {\varepsilon }_{22}$, using reverse substition.
Finite difference scheme:
I try to apply classical FDM, for example.
We can discretize the second-order derivatives using central finite differences:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \sigma^2} \approx \frac{u_{i+1, j}-2 u_{i, j}+u_{i-1, j}}{\Delta \sigma^2} \\[4pt] \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \tau^2} \approx \frac{u_{i, j+1}-2 u_{i, j}+u_{i, j-1}}{\Delta \tau^2}$$
​Substituting these into the PDE, we get:
$$
(\cosh \tau-\cos \sigma)^2\left(\frac{u_{i+1, j}-2 u_{i, j}+u_{i-1, j}}{\Delta \sigma^2}+\frac{u_{i, j+1}-2 u_{i, j}+u_{i, j-1}}{\Delta \tau^2}\right)-u_{i, j}=0
$$
Solving for $u_{i,j}$, we obtain the numerical scheme:
$$
u_{i, j}=\frac{\left(\cosh \tau_j-\cos \sigma_i\right)^2}{\left(\frac{\Delta \sigma}{\Delta \tau}\right)^2+1}\left(\frac{u_{i+1, j}+u_{i-1, j}}{\Delta \sigma^2}+\frac{u_{i, j+1}+u_{i, j-1}}{\Delta \tau^2}\right)
$$
Problem:
Classical FDM not work, and in result solution $u_{i,j}$ conatin larger values such as $2.185251484155436406e+296$.
My question: Please tell me, maybe there is one for such an equation, taking into account the bicylindrical (or rather even bipolar) coordinate systems? Are there any specific features of area sampling in this case? Because, most likely, this equation was solved, and there are quite some patterns that are stable for this mathematical model.
